# Url opens in multiple browsers and multiple tabs

Tags: 18.04, gnome, i3-wm

I have 4 web browsers on my system and I've set brave as the default browser. However, when I click on a url it opens in two different browsers - Brave & Chrome.

- If Brave is already running then the url opens in two new tabs and then one on a new chrome window.
- If Brave is not already running, then the url opens in 3 new tabs and then one on a new chrome window.

Screenshot of `xdg-open "http://example.com"`:

[image]

I have not used xdg-open before but here are the things that I tried.
I am on Ubuntu 18.04 with i3wm

---

I have removed every trace of chrome and any other browsers from
- `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list`
- `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`
- `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

---

Running `xdg-settings get default-web-browser` gives me 
`brave-browser.desktop`

---

Running `update-alternatives --list gnome-www-browser` gives me

```
/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
/usr/bin/vivaldi-stable
```

Running `update-alternatives --list x-www-browser` gives me

```
/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
/usr/bin/surf
```

---

Running `update-alternatives --display gnome-www-browser` gives me

```
gnome-www-browser - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
  link currently points to /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
  link gnome-www-browser is /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser
/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable - priority 200
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable - priority -50
/usr/bin/vivaldi-stable - priority -50
```

Running `update-alternatives --display x-www-browser` gives me

```
x-www-browser - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
  link currently points to /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable
  link x-www-browser is /usr/bin/x-www-browser
  slave x-www-browser.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/x-www-browser.1.gz
/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable - priority 200
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable - priority 50
/usr/bin/surf - priority 30
  slave x-www-browser.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/surf.1.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is actually with Brave, I had the same problem (with the same environment too, i3wm, ubuntu and chrome) and tracked it down to here https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/4142

From the issue, the problem will probably be solved in the next release

Comment: Do you have any temp fix ? I saw one on the github issue you provided but not sure how I can implement it.

Comment: You can always install the [beta channel of Brave](https://brave.com/download-beta/) in the meantime, I'm pretty sure it's already fixed in there. --

The fix in the github issue is to link the browser executable to a script that ignores the error, in my case the executable is in `/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable` (you can find it searching for the `brave-browser.desktop` file and looking the command executed in the `Exec` property inside the file).

Comment: I changed /usr/bin/brave-browser-stable. http://i.imgur.com/Hphd2bR.png. 
It didn't work. Can you please see if I made the right edit ?

Comment: I just wrapped the command in a subcommand and it worked (I don't know if it will cause any other incovenience, problably just a new process in the browser process tree). Anyway my file is a bit longer than your print so I published it fully, but I just changed the last line, you can copy it and put it on your file -- https://gist.github.com/augustobmoura/539a76527c57f1f6fde3e83a67f9db9f

Comment: Hey that worked ! Thank you so much